# SSL self signed certificate error for pip and AWS CLI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, pip, ssl-certificate

First, I have to say that I have no experience with SSL or certificates.

Second, the problem that I am facing shows up in two places (Edit: 3).

1. Whenever I do `pip install`, I get an error about a self-signed certificate in certificate chain.
2. Whenever I use the AWS CLI, I get a very similar looking error about a self-signed certificate.
3. I cannot install packages on atom. https://drive.google.com/file/d/19jjNy9zkRuHBli-fIQaUkX8strhdb76X/view?usp=sharing

Here are the 2 specific commands that I've used as well as their corresponding error messages. While I am only showing 2 specific commands, these errors show up with any pip or aws operation.

`pip install --upgrade pip`

Error Message:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping
```

`aws s3 ls`

Error Message:

```
SSL validation failed for https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1125)
```

I'm assuming that these two issues are somehow related, but I would like to ask about some context regarding SSL certificates.

1. Are SSL certificates stored in my own local computer? If so, how can I find them? In my Keychain Access, I only have 4 certificates, and none even remotely related to python or AWS.
2. Is the failing SSL certificate in both cases the same one? In other words, does my local computer store a single SSL certificate for all use cases, or are there two different SSL certificates for both cases?

Many stack overflow answers provide workarounds such as setting pypi.org as a trusted host in the command, or setting sslVerify to false, but ideally I'd like a solution that deals with the problem at its root or at least know why this is happening (pip was working fine before in the past).

Other potentially useful details:

- I am not using a company network
- I have checked to make sure that my system's date and time is correct.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you check `curl -v https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com` what certs do you get?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sFqhcawF This is the result of the output

Comment: The cert looks fine. So I don't know why would you get errors about self singing ssl.

Comment: Can you try from different computer or vm?

Comment: I just noticed that when I try to open the file, I get this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O2EU86YRdWAvPnxEeM36c88m9IrUnPfy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `aws s3 ls` works on another computer (also mac)